# can we know who access key vault resource

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-keyvault, azure-log-analytics

We are using Azure Key Vault to store our database connecting string and some password as secret. What are the ways to know who has accessed the key vault and which secret they accessed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you have to enable logging of audit events.
The docs have an article on it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-logging.

You will need a Storage account where the logs will be stored.
Then you enable logging of audit events.
Then you can check for SecretGet/SecretList events to see when someone read a secret.

The article above shows how to do it with PowerShell,
but you can also enable audit logging from the Portal under Diagnostic settings in the Key Vault blade.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [ARM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostic-settings-template) including Storage Account and Log Analytics:

```
"resources": [
  {
    "type": "/<resource namespace>/providers/diagnosticSettings",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceName'),'/microsoft.insights/', parameters('settingName'))]",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[<resource Id for Key Vault>]"
    ],
    "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
    "properties": {
      "name": "[parameters('settingName')]",
      "storageAccountId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]",
 "workspaceId": "[parameters('workspaceId')]",
      "logs": [ 
        {
          "category": "AuditEvent",
          "enabled": true
        }
      ],
      "metrics": [
        {
          "category": "AllMetrics",
          "enabled": true
        }
      ]
   }
  }
]
```